# MS Access VBA - Runtime Error 438 when setting ControlSource-Property in Form

Tags: vba, ms-access

After years of `MS-Access` abstinence, I decided to help a friend manage guesthouse bookings by writing a database for him.

To display bookings, I am building a form `frmHello` like this:

```
        Mon, Dec 2   Tue, Dec 3   Wed, Dec 4
--------------------------------------------
room 1  [Smith   ]   [Smith   ]   [Smith   ]  
--------------------------------------------
room 2  [        ]   [        ]   [Miller  ]  
--------------------------------------------
room 3  [        ]   [Adams   ]   [        ]
```

`[xxx     ]` are unbound textboxes. `frmHello` is unbound, `on_load` I call `Sub Init()` to organize the data in a (temporary) table `tblHello`, then bind `frmHello` to `tblHello` and bind the textboxes to their specific fields in `tblHello` in `Sub bind()`.

And this is where the mess started: `Microsoft Visual Basic` keeps reporting a `runtime-error 438: object doesn't support property or method` and marks line 5 below:

```
1    Private Sub bind()
2      Me.Recordsource = "tblHello"
3      For n = 0 to 3
4        Me("txtBooking" & n).ControlSource = "helloBooking" & n
5        Me("txtStatus" & n).ControlSource  = "helloStatus" & n  <------- marked line
6      Next
       ...
```

Note that line 4 runs perfectly...

What I've tried:

- deleted the `For ... Next`loop and wrote out all the textboxes' names and fields by hand
- double-checked all names etc.

**---> same error** :-(

**Who can help, please?**

I'm running Access 2019 64bit on Win 10.

Comment: Can you print `Me("txtStatus" & n).ControlType`? It should be equal to `acTextbox` if it truly is a textbox.

Comment: @ErikA shame on me! When checking, I found out I had a typo in the name of txtStatus0.name... sigh! Thank you!!